# Proof to the solution of Gambler's Ruin Problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have come across a problem known as **Gambler's Ruin Problem** but I can't find the derivation to its solution anywhere. Does anyone know how to prove it? I will really appreciate it. Thanks

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:**

Two gamblers, $A$ and $B$, are betting on the tosses of a fair coin. At the beginning of the game, player $A$ has $n_1$ coins and player $B$ has $n_2$ coins. So there are $n_1+n_2$ coins between them. In each play of the game, a fair coin is tossed. If the result of the coin toss is head, player $A$ collects $1$ coin from $B$. If the result of the coin toss is tail, player $A$ pays $B$ $1$ coin. The game continues until one of the players has all the coins. What is the probability that player $A$ ends up with all the coins? What is the probability that player $B$ ends up with all the coins?

**SOLUTION:**

The long run probability of player A winning all the coins is  $P_A=\frac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}.$

The long run probability of player B winning all the coins is  $P_B=\frac{n_2}{n_1+n_2}.$

Comment: See [Gambler's Ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

Comment: @lulu I have seen that already. There is no mention of proof anywhere.

Comment: There are two complete proofs provided there.  One via martingales requires some knowledge, the other is by linear recurrence requires no particular background.  More broadly, given the result (however obtained) it is easy to confirm that it satisfies the recursion and boundary conditions, and that too is a proof.

Comment: Are you talking about **Example of Huygens's result** mentioned there?

Comment: First proof begins "an argument is that..." and the second begins immediately after with ":Alternatively, this can be shown as follows."  The arguments are straightforward and take just a couple lines each.

Comment: It's about case: unfair coin being flipped. Here I am asking about the proof of case: fair coin being flipped. On wiki fair coin case is discussed but proof isn't mention but result is mentioned only.

Comment: the fair case is a special case of the unfair case, just set $p=q$.  Please try to work on this yourself.  The same paragraphs also cite Feller's classical text which should have been one of the first things you looked at.

Comment: Ok. I will do the rest. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Player $A$ has an equal probability of $0.5$ to either move up by one penny, or down by one penny, so $P(n) = 0.5\left[P(n+1) +P(n-1)\right]$

If you recall the mid-point theorem,
you'll understand that the relationship is linear, or you can rearrange the equation as
$P(n+1) - P(n) = P(n) - P(n-1)$, to see that the slope is constant.

The range over which play is possible is $(n_1+n_2)$ coins,
and obviously the greater the total fraction of coins you hold at start,
the better your chances,

thus P(A wins) = $\dfrac{n_1}{n_1+n_2}$
and P(B wins) = $\dfrac{n_2}{n_1+n_2}$